# Latest Version of Android Studio don't open in MacOS High Sierra 10.13

Tags: android-studio, macos-high-sierra

Yesterday I upgrade my machine to high sierra 10.13 but for some weird reason android studio doesn't open or get stuck, I use Android Studio 2.3 only for the Emulator since I work heavily on React Native. I made a lot of tricks but still having the same freeze screen.

try with sh studio.sh but the same result.

Image of App getting stuck or some weird behavior I never seen:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Android Studio 3.0.1 is supported on Mac® OS X® 10.10 (Yosemite) or higher, up to 10.13 (macOS High Sierra)

as mentioned on the website's System Requirements
https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html

One of the options you have is to downgrade macOS to run Android Studio the following explains how to do that:
https://www.macworld.co.uk/how-to/mac-software/how-remove-macos-high-sierra-downgrade-3581872/